# How pass dynamically Interface to a method?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, typescript-generics

I'm trying to pass a Typescript interface to a method using generics but I get this error on build time `Type error: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'I'.`

It seems that Interface isn't passed as expected

I'm new to typescript so I'm certainly doing it wrong. I'd read the doc multiple times watched tutorial but i don't get it.

My app is running in Next.js: 13.2.4 and TypeScript: 4.9.5

in my `/types.ts` file i have this interfaces

```
export interface IPage {
  data: {
    id:            number;
    user_created:  string;
    date_created:  Date;
    user_updated:  string;
    title:         string;
    content:       string;
  }
}

export interface IAnotherPage {
  data: {
    id:            number;
    user_created:  string;
    date_created:  Date;
    user_updated:  string;
    title:         string;
    content:       string;
    image:         string;
  } 
}
```

then in my `/app/page.tsx` i've this :

```
//@ts-check
import { IPageData, IPage} from '@/types';
import { makeTitle } from '@/utils/makeTitle';

export default async function Page({pageId: number}) {
    
    const pageData: IPageData = await getCollectionData('mypage', '?fields=*.*')    
    const metadatas = await makeTitle<IPageData>(pageData);

}
```

The reason why I would pass a interface from `page.tsx` to the method is because interface would depends which page is calling the method
for instance `/app/another/page.tsx` could look like this :

```
//@ts-check
import { IAnotherPageData } from '@/types';
import { makeTitle } from '@/utils/makeTitle';

export default async function AnotherPage({pageId: number}) {
    
    const pageData: IAnotherPageData = await getCollectionData('another_page', '?fields=*.*')
    const metadatas = await makeTitle<IAnotherPageData>(pageData);
}
```

and finally the file containing my makeTitle method `/utils/makeTitle.ts`

```
//@ts-check

export async function makeTitle<I>(pageData: I) {

    const title: string = pageData.data.title

    return title
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what the `I` refers to in `export async function makeTitle<I>(pageData: I)` and neither does the TypeScript compiler. Maybe you meant to do `export async function makeTitle<I extends IPageData>(pageData: I)`? Or even just `export async function makeTitle(pageData: IPageData)`?

Comment: But i'm calling `makeTitle` like this 
`const metadatas = await makeTitle<IPageData>(pageData);` 
I thought that `<IPageData>` would replace `<I>` isn't it ?

i can import Interface in `/makeTitle.ts` because i've different Interfaces for each different page that's why i'm trying to pass it dynamically.

thanks for your answer

Comment: So what happens when someone calls your function with `const metadatas = await makeTitle<Date>(new Date())`? Nothing in your function definition restricts that.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, generics are only useful when you refer to them at least twice. In this case you're only referring to it once so it's unnecessary.